# Does anyone know of a tech primer for Pivotal Cloud Cache in Spring MVC, not in Springboot?

Tags: spring, caching, cloud-foundry

Something similar to this : 
https://github.com/ramram43210/Java_Spring_2019/tree/master/Spring_2019/SpringDemo_cache_ehcache

I've seen the famous pizza app, but would like to see something without springboot.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found this pretty helpful. 
https://github.com/cf-gemfire-org/cloudcache-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/io/pivotal/MyJavaApplication.java